# SwiftUI ButtonStyle scaleEffect animates button position changes

Tags: ios, swiftui

we have couple of buttons that have a custom ButtonStyle set to them, that scales and changes alpha of these buttons on click. These buttons are in a sheet, that can be dragged. How can I prevent the position of the buttons be animated when using scaleEffect? Without the button style it's ok, but then obviously it won't animate on click. See gif for the problem. Thanks.

```
struct ScaleButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: ButtonStyleConfiguration) -> some View {
        configuration
            .label
            .animation(nil)
            .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.95 : 1)
            .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.8 : 1)
            .animation(.linear(duration: 0.2))
    }
}
```

[image: demonstration]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try link animation to related value, like

```
    .scaleEffect(configuration.isPressed ? 0.95 : 1)
    .opacity(configuration.isPressed ? 0.8 : 1)
    .animation(.linear(duration: 0.2), value: configuration.isPressed)
```